# Rolling back user edits that change a bad question into a bad question?

Tags: discussion

I found this post in the reopen queue:  [how to make checkbox in win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065214/c-win32-how-to-make-checkbox).  It's not a good question for SO.  No code to diagnose, no effort.  I am pretty sure it hit the reopen queue because the user edited it to include an answer that he devised.  Still no question, and nothing to diagnose, he added working code (plus a snarky comment directed at the people who closed).  I rolled that back and followed up with a comment.

Is that the best course of action?  Neither attempt resulted in an on-topic question for SO.  Should it be flagged for deletion instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you should always rollback edits that are obviously illegitimate or abusive. What you did there was the best course of action, and is something we appreciate.

There is no need to flag the question for immediate deletion. Give it a few days and if its status changes from [on hold] to [closed] and there is no sign of improvement in the question, feel free to vote to delete it if you haven't forgotten about it by then.

Comment: The only problem with not mashing the delete button ASAP is that these questions start to inexplicably gather "reopen" votes.