# Rolling back an obviously bad edit after a close vote?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I came across [this in my review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6208325). 
At [the state at which the queue saw it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26841252/2), it was pretty much garble.

However, the [edit log shows](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26841252/revisions) that a reasonable attempt was made to ask a question that was understandable, though the question would then be flagged for being `too broad` instead of `unclear`.

I'm a bit unsure as to whether a rollback is in order after the close vote, as it seems to me that in the process of rolling back, I am working against the vote I placed that the post, as presented, should be closed.

I believe it is in a similar vein to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258570/rolling-back-user-edits-that-change-a-bad-question-into-a-bad-question), but from a different pathway. Whereas that one is addressing bringing a question back open, I am not sure whether actively working to counter my close vote is something I should be doing.

Edit: Well, someone rolled it back in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit clearly makes the question worse.  It should be rolled back.

The fact that you've voted/flagged to close doesn't mean you shouldn't roll back an inappropriate edit.

Comment: OK, so I should assume them to be entirely separate tasks. Got it.